# Lie Group Homomorphism from $U(n)$ into $SO(2)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-homomorphism, unitary-matrices

The task was to find an *onto* Lie Group Homomorphism from $U(n)$ *onto* $SO(2)$ and I know how to do this.

My prof then said that the crux was that the task said **onto**, if it would have said **into** you could have just used the identity map. I can't get my head around this statement.

I mean $id(AB)=id(A)id(B)=AB$ with $A,B \in U(n)$ is obviously not in $SO(2)$, is it?

Comment: I think the professor just means the map $g \to 1_{SO(2)}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not a map from $SU(n)$ into $SO(2,\mathbb R)$. What your teacher meant was the map $M\mapsto e_{SO(2,\mathbb R)}$.

But consider the map $\det\colon U(n)\longrightarrow\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, and the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\psi\colon&\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}&\longrightarrow&GL(2,\mathbb R)\\&a+bi&\mapsto&\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}.\end{array}$$Then $\psi\circ\det$ is a group homomorphism and its image is precisely $SO(2,\mathbb R)$, since\begin{align}\det\bigl(U(n)\bigr)&=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid\lvert z\rvert=1\}\\&=\bigl\{\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\mid\theta\in\mathbb R\bigr\}.\end{align}